# Serialization Exception when attempting to receive Azure Service bus message via Topic/Subscriptions

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-sdk-.net, azure-servicebus-queues

I am recieving a Serialization Exception when attempting to parse the messaage recieved when subscribed to an Azure Service Bus topic.  Anyone see what I am missing?  I am using the Microsoft.ServiceBus.Samples.Messaging for the the Silverlight code.

I have a webservice with the following code:

```
public void PushCommand(Command command, int posLocationId)
{
    var topicName = "topicName";
    var topicClient = TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString, topicName);

    try
    {
         var message = new BrokeredMessage("test");
         topicClient.Send(message);
    }
    ...
}
```

I have a SilverLightClient with the following code:

```
private void OnReceiveMessageCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
{
     var subscriptionClient = (SubscriptionClient)result.AsyncState;
     try
     {
         var message = subscriptionClient.EndReceive(result);

         if (message != null)
         {
             String s = message.GetBody<string>();
         }

         // prep for next message
         subscriptionClient.BeginReceive(this.OnReceiveMessageCompleted, subscriptionClient);

     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        //unknown error
     }
}
```

SerializationException was caught
There was an error deserializing the object of type System.String. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Stacktrace:

```
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(Stream stream)
at Microsoft.Samples.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage.GetBody[T]()
at Common.SubscriptionManager.OnReceiveMessageCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
```

Comment: Have you tried just doing `subscriptionClient.Receive()`? Does that give the same error?

Comment: try getting the body of the message as object
Object obj = message.GetBody<object>();

Comment: It seems the message you try to receive is not correctly serialized.  Are you sure there is no message on the queue from an earlier try that does not serialize to a string?

Comment: @TheDude I don't have a Receive Method from the SilverLight code, I will try looking into if I can expose it.

Comment: @NavaRajan I get the same error when I use object

Comment: @SamVanhoutte I tried deleting the Topic and recreated it and still have the error.

Comment: @kjsteuer You can serialize the string and send it as byte stream and at the receiving end you can deserialize to string. It will work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue isn't in your SL code, it's in your sender code. When sending the message, the default implementation uses a binary message serializer, but the SL implementation uses DataContractSerializer, which depends on XML formatted messages. To fix the issue, your message send needs to do something like this:

```
DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(string));
queueClient.Send(new BrokeredMessage("test", ser));
```

On Service Bus, the body content is pretty much a bag of bytes-- the sender and receiver need to agree on how those things will be encoded/decoded.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks Scott! Are there any articles around the pros/cons of the different Serializers?

Comment: Sorry this took so long to respond too (5 years). Looking at pros/cons of the different serializers isn't really interesting. You serialize using the format that the consumer(s) needs. If most consumers can handle JavaScript, use that. If they can do binary serialization, use that. If you need custom serialization, go that path. All that stated, JSON serializers have the best portability/usability across languages (easiest to parse/read/implement) of all serialization mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize the string and send it as byte stream and at the receiving end you can deserialize to string. It will work.